# How can I set ENV from a path

Tags: osx, zsh, homebrew, readlink, dirname

I just installed `android-sdk` using Homebrew.

The path is `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1`.

I know I can export `ANDROID_HOME` with that value.

How can I set it dynamically using the real path of a command such as `sdkmanager'?

So far, I found

```
$ readlink /usr/local/bin/sdkmanager                                                                                                                  
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

How can I set `$ANDROID_HOME` from this value?

So that I have

```
$ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1
```

?

```
$ dirname `readlink /usr/local/bin/sdkmanager`                                                                                                        
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin
```

Now how can I append `../..`?

Comment: Related installation instructions with comments [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering for my own question.

There a handy symlink in `/usr/local/share`.

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/share
$ ls -l android-sdk
.... android-sdk -> /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1
```

Now I can export

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/user/local/share/android-sdk
```